# IE9 Background Image border outline (removal)

Tags: asp.net, html, css, internet-explorer

I made a page background with an image cut into small pieces to generate the background.

However in internet explorer 9 I have issues with the background images having an outline.  This does not occur in Firefox 4 or Chrome.

What's the CSS property to remove this?

```
.bottomright {background-image: url(../Images/Forms/form15.png);}
```

Comment: Code...Images...Links? Any, preferably all, of these would help us to help you.

Comment: There's not much code to display for this situation.  There must be some CSS property out there which makes it so you can remove that outline that appears in IE.

Comment: But we don't know what outline you are talking about. Without anything to have a look at, we'd be clutching at straws.

Comment: consider mocking up an example at http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com.

Comment: check your background image , may be it inherit borders..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gNSuj/2/

In IE9, the above jfiddle isn't showing an outline.

Only time I've seen it apply the outline is on links (including image links) and to get rid of that you add-

```
a:active, a:focus {
     outline: none;
}
```